# How to debug a service that "crashes" Upstart (supervisor, in this case)

Tags: 14.04, upstart, init, init.d, supervisor

I running Ubuntu 14.04. I have several services configured to run on boot, one of which is supervisor. I boot into runlevel 2, so all of the services in `/etc/rc2.d/` should be started at boot.

`/etc/rc2.d/S20supervisor` runs the supervisor startup script at `/etc/init.d/supervisor`, as it is supposed to. I see the script execute in `/var/log/boot.log`. Every script which should run after it does not. It is as if the supervisor script "crashes" Upstart.

If I edit `S20supervisor` to `S10supervisor`, that causes supervisor to execute first, and nothing else executes. After this, supervisor is running normally.

If I edit `S20supervisor` to `s99supervisor`, that causes supervisor to execute last, and everything else executes. After this, supervisor is running normally.

So it seems the service starts without issue, but for some reason Upstart locks up and won't execute any scripts after the supervisor script. Why?

As a note, I am able to start supervisor manually without issue with `sudo service supervisor start`, albeit with the following ouput:

`$ sudo service supervisor start
Starting supervisor: 2017-05-20 00:14:04,435 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-05-20 00:14:04,435 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/graphite.conf" during parsing
2017-05-20 00:14:04,450 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-05-20 00:14:04,450 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-05-20 00:14:04,450 INFO supervisord started with pid 4462
2017-05-20 00:14:05,455 INFO spawned: 'statsd' with pid 4465
2017-05-20 00:14:05,458 INFO spawned: 'carbon-cache' with pid 4466
2017-05-20 00:14:05,464 INFO spawned: 'graphite-webapp' with pid 4467
2017-05-20 00:14:06,635 INFO success: statsd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-05-20 00:14:06,635 INFO success: carbon-cache entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-05-20 00:14:06,635 INFO success: graphite-webapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)`

Comment: Answer: supervisor is running in the foreground instead of the background, so the Upstart script doesn't crash. It is hanging because supervisor is keeping control of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor is running in the foreground instead of the background, so the Upstart script doesn't crash: it is hanging because supervisor is keeping control of the thread.

The solution will be to make supervisor go to the background after starting up, but I'll post more details once I actually execute the fix.